# Stopping java.awt.Robot with a JButton

Tags: java

So I'm making a program which utilizes a Robot to copy and paste text. However, I've hit a wall when it comes to how to stop the Robot in the middle of its actions (I prefer using a button since the whole application is in a GUI). Right now I have it so that the Robot is created and starts when a different button is clicked, and it stops after a certain amount of messages. From what I understand you need to stop the thread it's on, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
public void initSpam() throws AWTException
{

    Robot bot = new Robot();
    isRunning = true;

    int delayTime;
    if(isDefault)
        delayTime = DEFAULT;
    else
        delayTime = customTime;

    StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(spam);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

    bot.delay(1250);

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer; i++) {
        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        bot.delay(delayTime);
    }

}
```

The above is the method that's called when the other JButton is pressed. If anyone could guide me how to do this and explain how all of this threading works/how to work with it properly (assume I don't know much), I'd greatly appreciate it. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to continuously execute a series of repeating actions, `javax.swing.Timer` is the way to go:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    private static final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, Main::run);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        final JButton startButton = new JButton("start");
        startButton.addActionListener(e -> timer.start());
        frame.add(startButton);

        final JButton stopButton = new JButton("stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(e -> timer.stop());
        frame.add(stopButton);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void run(final ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("do stuff");
    }
}
```

You should not call `sleep` or `delay` or they will make your button unresponsive. The delays should be only controlled by `Timer` object.

If your action is more complex and you need sleeps/delays in random places, it might be easier to create new thread:

```
private static Thread thread;

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    ...

    startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        thread = new Thread(Main::run);
        thread.start();
    });
    stopButton.addActionListener(e -> thread.interrupt());
}

private static void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("do stuff");
        }
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Each time you call `Thread.sleep` from your worker thread it will throw `InterruptedException` if the main thread interrupted it.

Keep in mind, that you cannot interact with most of AWT components from your new thread. Even if you want to change a text on a label you have to do that through `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait`. You should also not share any mutable state between those threads - unless properly synchronized. Stick with the first option, even if it slightly complicates your code - not having to deal with threads is usually worth it.

Comment: The first set works perfectly! This makes a bit more sense now so thank you for that. Do you know of any places that I can read up more about threads? I'm guessing if I understood them better it'd probably help me figure out where and where not to use them (if needed).

Comment: [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html) are probably a good start.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread workThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //WORK initspam here
    }
});
```

to stop work, on click call:

```
workThread.interrupt();
```

in the initSpam add:

```
   for (..) {
      if (Thread.interrupted()) {
          break;
      }
   }
```